# If $\{A\} \subseteq P(B)$, show that $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If $\{A\} \subseteq P(B)$, show that $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$.

$\{A\} \subseteq P(B) \implies A \in B$

That's the only thing I could think of.  I would like help.

Comment: The hypothesis does not imply $A\in B$; in fact it says $A\in P(B)$, which is the sane as $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\mathcal P(B)$ is the set of all subsets of $B$. Hence, $\{A\}\subseteq \mathcal P(B)$, which is equivalent to $A\in \mathcal P(B)$, states that $A$ is a subset of $B$, in symbols $A\subseteq B$. In particular, any subset of $A$ is also a subset of $B$ since $\subseteq$ is transitive. We conclude that $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq \mathcal P(B)$.

Comment: conclude based on what?

Comment: Every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$ means that every element of $\mathcal P(A)$ is an element of $\mathcal P(B)$ which in turn means that $\mathcal P(A)$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(B)$.